# Как добавить 2 Entity c ForingKey используя EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Есть 2 Класса Category-Shop , где внешний ключ в Category.ShopId-Shop.ShopId

```
    public class Shop
    {    
    [Key]
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categorys { get; set; }
    }
public class Category
    {
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public Shop Shop { get; set; }
    public int? ShopId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Пытаюсь добавить 2 Entity

```
  using(Db db = new Db())
    {
    Shop shop = new() { ShopId = 1, Name = "shop" };
    Category cat = new Category() { CategoryId = 1, Name = "ygy", ShopId = 1 };
db.Shops.Add(shop);
    db.Categorys.Add(cat);
 db.SaveChangesAsync().Wait();
    }
```

при этом вылетает исключение
Невозможно вставить явное значение для столбца идентификаторов в таблице , когда параметр IDENTITY_INSERT имеет значение OFF entity

Answer (score 1):

Айдишники типа `int` по умолчанию будут генерироваться в БД. Поэтому не нужно манипулировать ими вручную в коде. Просто не задавайте их - это произойдёт автоматически.

Создаём сущности:

```
Shop shop = new() { Name = "shop" };
Category cat = new Category() { Name = "ygy" };
```

Связываем их. Достаточно одной из эти строк!

```
// Или так:
shop.Categories.Add(cat);
// Или так:
cat.Shop = shop;
```

Добавляем сущности в контекст. Достаточно одной из эти строк!

```
// Или так:
db.Shops.Add(shop);
// Или так:
db.Categories.Add(cat);
```

Так как сущности связаны между собой, они обе добавятся в контекст автоматически.

---

Никогда так не делайте:

```
db.SaveChangesAsync().Wait();
```

Пишите просто:

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

А лучше используйте асинхронность:

```
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

При этом метод, внутри которого вызывается эта строка, должен быть `async`.

Comment: '    public class Shop
        {    
        [Key]
        public int ShopId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Category> Categorys { get; set; }=new List<Category>();
        }
 
    }' На  ICollection<Category> Categorys { get; set; }    необходимо оказывается также добавить  =new List<Category>();  иначе NullReferenceExeption

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Shop
    {    
    [Key]
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categorys { get; set; }=new List<Category>();
    }
```

на `ICollection<Category> Categorys { get; set; }` необходимо оказывается также добавить '**=new List();**'

```
public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
```

иначе **NullReferenceExeption**Это если при связывании мы добавляем к одному многих через коллекцию